# DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0 - audience network NativeAdSample

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

when running the NativeAdSample app from the last Facebook SDK, I got this message in console log:

```
DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
```

Any idea what that's mean ?

Comment: Is this Cordova or React Native?

Comment: neither........

Comment: I've got the same error on Capacitor which is basically kind of Cordova

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this message in Xcode when you build the app? Think it's due to Safari Mobile Browser cookies. Was able to clear the message after using the following shell commands:

```
rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies;
pkill -U $(whoami) nsurlstoraged;
```

Not sure if that approach is recommended. The solution is not advised in the following thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6826082, And may be caused by files having incorrect permissions, access control, or locks.